# UITextField: move view when keyboard appears

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

I'm currently working on an iPhone application with a single view, which has multiple UITextFields for input. When the keyboard shows, it overlays the bottom textfields. So I added the corresponding `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` method, to move the view up, which works great:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if ( ( textField != inputAmount ) && ( textField != inputAge ) ) {
        NSTimeInterval animationDuration = 0.300000011920929;
        CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
        frame.origin.y -= kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;
        frame.size.height += kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"ResizeForKeyboard" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
        self.view.frame = frame;
        [UIView commitAnimations];      
    }
}
```

This method checks, if the source of the message is one of the textfields that are visible when the keyboard shows, and if not, it moves the view up.

I also added the `textFieldDidEndEnditing:` method, which moves the view down again (and updates some model objects according to the changed input):

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if ( ( textField != inputMenge ) && ( textField != inputAlter ) ) {
        NSTimeInterval animationDuration = 0.300000011920929;
        CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
        frame.origin.y += kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;
        frame.size.height -= kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"ResizeForKeyboard" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
        self.view.frame = frame;
        [UIView commitAnimations];      
    }
    // Additional Code
}
```

However, this solution has a simple flaw: When I finish editing one of the "hidden" textfields and touch another textfield, the keyboard vanishes, the view moves down, the view moves up again and the keyboard reappears.

Is there any possibility to keep the keyboard from vanishing and reappearing between two edits (of the "hidden" textfields - so that the view only moves when the selected textfield changes from one that would be hidden by the keyboard to one that would not be hidden)?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This solution is based on ComSubVie's one.

Advantages:

- It supports device rotation - works for all orientations;
- It doesn't hardcode the values for animation duration and curve, it reads them from the keyboard notification;
- It utilizes `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` instead of `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` to sync keyboard animation and custom actions;
- It doesn't use the deprecated `UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey`;
- It handles keyboard resize due to pressing the International key;
- Fixed memory leak by unregistering for keyboard events;
- All keyboard handling code is encapsulated in a separate class - `KBKeyboardHandler`;
- Flexibility - `KBKeyboardHandler` class may be easy extended / modified to better suit specific needs;

Limitations:

- Works for iOS 4 and above, it needs small modifications to support older versions;
- It works for applications with a single `UIWindow`. If you use multiple UIWindows, you may need to modify `retrieveFrameFromNotification:` method.

Usage:

Include KBKeyboardHandler.h, KBKeyboardHandler.m and KBKeyboardHandlerDelegate.h in your project. Implement the `KBKeyboardHandlerDelegate` protocol in your view controller - it consists of a single method, which will be called when keyboard is shown, hidden or its size is changed. Instantiate the `KBKeyboardHandler` and set its delegate (typically self). See sample `MyViewController` below.

**KBKeyboardHandler.h**:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol KBKeyboardHandlerDelegate;

@interface KBKeyboardHandler : NSObject

- (id)init;

// Put 'weak' instead of 'assign' if you use ARC
@property(nonatomic, assign) id<KBKeyboardHandlerDelegate> delegate; 
@property(nonatomic) CGRect frame;

@end
```

**KBKeyboardHandler.m**:

```
#import "KBKeyboardHandler.h"
#import "KBKeyboardHandlerDelegate.h"

@implementation KBKeyboardHandler

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                                     name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                                   object:nil];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                                                     name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                                   object:nil];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [super dealloc];
}

@synthesize delegate;
@synthesize frame;

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    CGRect oldFrame = self.frame;    
    [self retrieveFrameFromNotification:notification];

    if (oldFrame.size.height != self.frame.size.height)
    {
        CGSize delta = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width - oldFrame.size.width,
                                  self.frame.size.height - oldFrame.size.height);
        if (self.delegate)
            [self notifySizeChanged:delta notification:notification];
    }
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if (self.frame.size.height > 0.0)
    {
        [self retrieveFrameFromNotification:notification];
        CGSize delta = CGSizeMake(-self.frame.size.width, -self.frame.size.height);

        if (self.delegate)
            [self notifySizeChanged:delta notification:notification];
    }

    self.frame = CGRectZero;
}

- (void)retrieveFrameFromNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    CGRect keyboardRect;
    [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] getValue:&keyboardRect];
    self.frame = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController.view convertRect:keyboardRect fromView:nil];
}

- (void)notifySizeChanged:(CGSize)delta notification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSDictionary *info = [notification userInfo];

    UIViewAnimationOptions curve;
    [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] getValue:&curve];

    NSTimeInterval duration;
    [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] getValue:&duration];

    void (^action)(void) = ^{
        [self.delegate keyboardSizeChanged:delta];
    };

    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration
                          delay:0.0
                        options:curve
                     animations:action
                     completion:nil];    
}

@end
```

**KBKeyboardHandlerDelegate.h**:

```
@protocol KBKeyboardHandlerDelegate

- (void)keyboardSizeChanged:(CGSize)delta;

@end
```

Sample **MyViewController.h**:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController<KBKeyboardHandlerDelegate>
...
@end
```

Sample **MyViewController.m**:

```
@implementation MyViewController
{
    KBKeyboardHandler *keyboard;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    keyboard.delegate = nil;
    [keyboard release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    keyboard = [[KBKeyboardHandler alloc] init];
    keyboard.delegate = self;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    keyboard.delegate = nil;
    [keyboard release];
    keyboard = nil;
}

- (void)keyboardSizeChanged:(CGSize)delta
{
    // Resize / reposition your views here. All actions performed here 
    // will appear animated.
    // delta is the difference between the previous size of the keyboard 
    // and the new one.
    // For instance when the keyboard is shown, 
    // delta may has width=768, height=264,
    // when the keyboard is hidden: width=-768, height=-264.
    // Use keyboard.frame.size to get the real keyboard size.

    // Sample:
    CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
    frame.size.height -= delta.height;
    self.view.frame = frame;
}
```

UPDATE: Fixed iOS 7 warning, thanks @weienv.

Comment: Real nifty solution. Works great!

Comment: Still works in iOS 7! You do get a warning because [UIView animateWithDuration:...] takes a UIViewAnimationOptions instead of UIViewAnimationCurve, so changing that type clears up that implicit cast. Thanks for the lightweight solution.

Comment: It doesn't work for me on iOS 7. I changed UIViewAnimationCurve to UIViewAnimationOptions, and also the "assign" to "weak". I'm using Xcode 6, has something changed?

Comment: Awesome! Works like a charm!

Answer (score 29):

I just solved this problem. The solution is a combination of a `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` and `UIKeyboardDidHideNotification` observer with the above `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` and `textFieldDidEndEditing:` methods.

You need three additional variables, one to store the current selected UITextField (which I have named activeField), one to indicate if the current view has been moved, and one to indicate if the keyboard is displayed.

This is how the two `UITextField` delegate methods look now:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    activeField = textField;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    activeField = nil;
    // Additional Code
}
```

When the view is loaded, the following two observers are created:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    // Additional Code
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
                                               object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWasHidden:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification
                                               object:nil];
}
```

And the corresponding methods are implemented as follows:

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    if ( keyboardShown )
        return;

    if ( ( activeField != inputAmount ) && ( activeField != inputAge ) ) {
        NSDictionary *info = [aNotification userInfo];
        NSValue *aValue = [info objectForKey:UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey];
        CGSize keyboardSize = [aValue CGRectValue].size;

        NSTimeInterval animationDuration = 0.300000011920929;
        CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
        frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height-44;
        frame.size.height += keyboardSize.height-44;
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"ResizeForKeyboard" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
        self.view.frame = frame;
        [UIView commitAnimations];

        viewMoved = YES;
    }

    keyboardShown = YES;
}

- (void)keyboardWasHidden:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    if ( viewMoved ) {
        NSDictionary *info = [aNotification userInfo];
        NSValue *aValue = [info objectForKey:UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey];
        CGSize keyboardSize = [aValue CGRectValue].size;

        NSTimeInterval animationDuration = 0.300000011920929;
        CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
        frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height-44;
        frame.size.height -= keyboardSize.height-44;
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"ResizeForKeyboard" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
        self.view.frame = frame;
        [UIView commitAnimations];

        viewMoved = NO;
    }

    keyboardShown = NO;
}
```

This code works now as expected. The keyboard is only dismissed when the Done button is pressed, otherwise it stays visible and the view is not moved around.

As an additional note, I think it is possible to get the `animationDuration` dynamically by asking the `NSNotification` object, since I have already played with a similar solution but didn't get it to work (which it does now).

Comment: What happens if the user brings the keyboard up in landscape mode and then rotates to portrait mode? The keyboard height is different, which means you will move the frame.origin.y an incorrect amount.

Comment: Just a note to those who might not catch this.  You need add to your .h file: UITextField *activeField; BOOL keyboardShown; BOOL viewMoved;

Comment: Good, though instead of hardcoding the `animationDuration` and `animationCurve` values, you should use the `UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey` and `UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey` userInfo values.

Comment: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification -> UIKeyboardWillShowNotification ?

Comment: You are missing the viewDidUnload

Comment: I get keyboardDidShow:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance I am using UITextView not textField

Comment: UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey is deprecated. Also @Odelya, using viewDidUnload is deprecated.

Comment: What are inputAmount and inputAge?

Comment: what is inputAmount and inputAge ??

Comment: 0.300000011920929 is that some Taliban secret code?

Answer (score 2):

This view controller must be `UITextView` Delegate and you must set `self.textview.delegate = self` in `viewdidload`

```
 -(void) textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
    {
        NSLog(@"%f",self.view.frame.origin.y);
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25f];
        CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
        frame.origin.y =frame.origin.y -204;
        [self.view setFrame:frame];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }

-(void) textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25f];
    CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
    frame.origin.y = frame.origin.y + 204;
    [self.view setFrame:frame];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I got your Problem just do simple thing
>   just give outlet to UIScrollview.
>   set unique Tag property for  each textfield in view.

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
    {   
        switch (textField.tag)
        {
            case 2:    //can be your textfiled tag
              { CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0, yourtextfield.frame.origin.y-150); 
                                           //set figure y-150 as per your comfirt
                  [scrollview setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES]; 
             }break;

              case 3:   
              { CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0, yourtextfield.frame.origin.y-180); 
                                           //set figure y-180 as per your comfirt
                  [scrollview setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES]; 
             }break;

             ...

         }
    }

    -(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

        if(textField.tag==3){
            [scrollview setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];
                }
         //set the last textfield when you want to disappear keyboard.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Write below code in your view controller. tbl is your table view. 

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillChangeFrame:) name:UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}



#pragma mark - Keyboard Methods
-(void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
//    375 × 667  ( 750 × 1334 ) iPhone 6
    //414 × 736
    CGRect keyboardRect = [[[notification userInfo] valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    int H = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height - 64- 20 -keyboardRect.size.height;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        tbl.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(tbl.contentInset.top, tbl.contentInset.left, H, tbl.contentInset.right);
    }];
}

-(void)keyboardWillChangeFrame:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    CGRect keyboardRect = [[[notification userInfo] valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
//    int H = IS_IPHONE_5?504-keyboardRect.size.height:416-keyboardRect.size.height;
     int H = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height - 64- 20  -keyboardRect.size.height;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        //        scroll.frame = rect;
        tbl.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(tbl.contentInset.top, tbl.contentInset.left, H, tbl.contentInset.right);
    }];
}


-(void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification
{

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        //        scroll.frame = rect;
        tbl.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(tbl.contentInset.top, tbl.contentInset.left, 0, tbl.contentInset.right);
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Fairly easy solution, works with all screen sizes

First you have to embed you UITextFields to a UIScrollView. In my case, I had several UITextFields and a UITextView.

[image]

Then you have to inherit from UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate.

`class SettingsVC: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate`

Assign textfield's and textview's delegates to self.

`fullNameTextField.delegate = self
 usernameTextField.delegate = self
 websiteTextField.delegate = self
 profileDescription.delegate = self`

Then use this code:

```js
var editingTextInput: UIView!


override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(self.keyboardShown(notification:)),
                                           name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidShow,
                                           object: nil)
    

  }
  
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidShow, object: nil)
  }
  
  func keyboardShown(notification: NSNotification) {
    
    if let infoKey  = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey],
      let rawFrame = (infoKey as AnyObject).cgRectValue {
      
      let keyboardFrame = view.convert(rawFrame, to: view)
      let editingTextInputFrame = self.editingTextInput.convert(self.editingTextInput.frame, to: view)

      
      if editingTextInputFrame.maxY > keyboardFrame.minY{
        
        let diff = keyboardFrame.minY - editingTextInputFrame.maxY
        containerScrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: -diff), animated: true)
        
      }
    }
  }
  
  func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    self.editingTextInput = textField
  }
  
  func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    self.editingTextInput = textView
  }
  
  func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    containerScrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: true)
  }
  
  func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    containerScrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: true)
  }
```

In short, you subscribe to UIKeyboardDidShow notification.
When you tap on textField or textView keyboard is shown and you grab keyboard's frame and frame of input element you have tapped on. Convert them to viewController's coordinate system and compare input element's lowest point to a keyboard's highest. If element's lower part is lower than keyboard's highest, than set offset of containerScrollView to the difference between them.

```js
if editingTextInputFrame.maxY > keyboardFrame.minY{
            
            let diff = keyboardFrame.minY - editingTextInputFrame.maxY
            containerScrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: -diff), animated: true)
            
          }
```

[image: res1]
[image: res2]

Answer (score 0):

Like I mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61543669/7063931):

I've developed a framework for my own need to solve this issue better, and made it public now. It's not just for UITextField and UITextView, It works for any custom UIView that adopts UITextInput protocol like UITextField and UITextView and offers many useful features. You can install it via Carthage, CocoaPods or Swift Package Manager.

[ODScrollView GitHub](https://github.com/orcundeniz/ODScrollView)

[ODScrollView Medium](https://link.medium.com/hmMLg70B85)

> ODScrollView is just a UIScrollView that automatically moves editable text areas like UITextField and UITextView vertically depending on keyboard visibility to offer better user experience.

### Features

- Automatically moves first responder UIViews that adopt the UITextInput protocol up/down when the keyboard appears/disappears, e.g., UITextField, UITextView, UISearchTextField or any custom UIView that adopts UITextInput protocol.

  - Note that if UITextInput's frame does NOT fits the remaining area between ODScrollView and keyboard, then ODScrollView adjusts UITextInput based on cursor position instead of frame. In such cases, "trackTextInputCursor" feature can be used. [Example](https://github.com/orcundeniz/ODScrollView/blob/master/docs/GIFs/ExamplesForSettings.md#alwaysallbottomtrackcursor)
- Adjustment margin can be applied for each UITextInput seperately for .Top and .Bottom adjustment direction setting. 20 CGFloat by default.
- Adjustment can be enabled/disabled for each UITextInput seperately. true by default.
- Adjustment directon - .Top, .Center, .Bottom - can be applied for each UITextInput seperately. .Bottom by default. [Example](https://github.com/orcundeniz/ODScrollView/blob/master/docs/GIFs/ExamplesForSettings.md#alwaysbottomuitextviewsandcenteruitextfieldsandrest)
- Adjustment options determines how ODScrollView adjusts. .Always by default.

  - .Always : ODScrollView always adjusts the UITextInput which is placed anywhere in the ODScrollView regardless UITextInput overlaps or not with shown keyboard. [Example](https://github.com/orcundeniz/ODScrollView/blob/master/docs/GIFs/ExamplesForSettings.md#alwaysallbottom)
  - .IfNeeded : ODScrollView only adjusts the UITextInput if it overlaps with the shown keyboard. [Example](https://github.com/orcundeniz/ODScrollView/blob/master/docs/GIFs/ExamplesForSettings.md#ifneededallcenter)
- Besides UIScrollView.keyboardDismissModes, the keyboard can be dismissed by tapping a UIView which is provided by ODScrollViewDelegate. After the keyboard is dismissed, ODScrollView can return its original position. nil and false by default. [Example](https://github.com/orcundeniz/ODScrollView/blob/master/docs/GIFs/ExamplesForSettings.md#alwaysallbottomtrackcursor)

### Usage

**1 -** First thing you need to do is setting up ODScrollView and its content view properly. Since ODScrollView is just a UIScrollView, you can implement ODScrollView same way you do for UIScrollView. It's up to you to create ODScrollView by using storyboard or programmatically.

If you're creating ODScrollView programmatically, you can continue from step 4.

Suggested way to create UIScrollView in Storyboard

```
- If you are using Content Layout Guide and Frame Layout Guide:
    1.1 - scrollView: Place UIScrollView anywhere you want to use.  
    1.2 - contentView: Place UIView inside scrollView.
    1.3 - Set contentView's top, bottom, leading and trailing constraints to Content Layout Guide's constraints.
    1.4 - Set contentView's width equal to Frame Layout Guide's width.
    1.5 - Set contentView's height equal to Frame Layout Guide's height or set static height which is larger than scrollView's height.
    1.6 - Build your UI inside contentView.

- If you are NOT using Content Layout Guide and Frame Layout Guide:
    1.1 - scrollView: Place UIScrollView anywhere you want to use.  
    1.2 - contentView: Place UIView inside scrollView.
    1.3 - Set contentView's top, bottom, leading and trailing constraints to 0.
    1.4 - Set contentView's width equal to scrollView's width.
    1.5 - Set contentView's height equal to scrollView's superview's height or set static height which is larger than scrollView's height.
    1.6 - Build your UI inside contentView.
```

**2 -** Change the scrollView's class from UIScrollView to ODScrollView in the identity inspector on Storyboard.

**3 -** Create IBOutlets for scrollView and contentView on ViewController.

**4 -** Call the following methods inside ViewDidLoad() on ViewController:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //ODScrollView setup
    scrollView.registerContentView(contentView)
    scrollView.odScrollViewDelegate = self
}
```

**5 -** Optional: You still can use UIScrollView's features:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //ODScrollView setup
    scrollView.registerContentView(contentView)
    scrollView.odScrollViewDelegate = self

    // UIScrollView setup
    scrollView.delegate = self // UIScrollView Delegate
    scrollView.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag // UIScrollView keyboardDismissMode. Default is .none.

    UITextView_inside_contentView.delegate = self
}
```

**6 -** Adopt ODScrollViewDelegate from ViewController and decide ODScrollView options:

```swift
extension ViewController: ODScrollViewDelegate {

    // MARK:- State Notifiers: are responsible for notifiying ViewController about what is going on while adjusting. You don't have to do anything if you don't need them.

    // #Optional
    // Notifies when the keyboard showed.
    func keyboardDidShow(by scrollView: ODScrollView) {}

    // #Optional
    // Notifies before the UIScrollView adjustment.
    func scrollAdjustmentWillBegin(by scrollView: ODScrollView) {}

    // #Optional
    // Notifies after the UIScrollView adjustment.
    func scrollAdjustmentDidEnd(by scrollView: ODScrollView) {}

    // #Optional
    // Notifies when the keyboard hid.
    func keyboardDidHide(by scrollView: ODScrollView) {}

    // MARK:- Adjustment Settings

    // #Optional
    // Specifies the margin between UITextInput and ODScrollView's top or bottom constraint depending on AdjustmentDirection
    func adjustmentMargin(for textInput: UITextInput, inside scrollView: ODScrollView) -> CGFloat {
        if let textField = textInput as? UITextField, textField == self.UITextField_inside_contentView {
            return 20
        } else {
            return 40
        }
    }

    // #Optional
    // Specifies that whether adjustment is enabled or not for each UITextInput seperately.
    func adjustmentEnabled(for textInput: UITextInput, inside scrollView: ODScrollView) -> Bool {
        if let textField = textInput as? UITextField, textField == self.UITextField_inside_contentView {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }


    // Specifies adjustment direction for each UITextInput. It means that  some of UITextInputs inside ODScrollView can be adjusted to the bottom, while others can be adjusted to center or top.
    func adjustmentDirection(selected textInput: UITextInput, inside scrollView: ODScrollView) -> AdjustmentDirection {
        if let textField = textInput as? UITextField, textField == self.UITextField_inside_contentView {
            return .bottom
        } else {
            return .center
        }
    }

    /**
     - Always : ODScrollView always adjusts the UITextInput which is placed anywhere in the ODScrollView.
     - IfNeeded : ODScrollView only adjusts the UITextInput if it overlaps with the shown keyboard.
     */
    func adjustmentOption(for scrollView: ODScrollView) -> AdjustmentOption {
        .Always
    }

    // MARK: - Hiding Keyboard Settings

    /**
     #Optional

     Provides a view for tap gesture that hides keyboard.

     By default, keyboard can be dismissed by keyboardDismissMode of UIScrollView.

     keyboardDismissMode = .none
     keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag
     keyboardDismissMode = .interactive

     Beside above settings:

     - Returning UIView from this, lets you to hide the keyboard by tapping the UIView you provide, and also be able to use isResettingAdjustmentEnabled(for scrollView: ODScrollView) setting.

     - If you return nil instead of UIView object, It means that hiding the keyboard by tapping is disabled.
     */
    func hideKeyboardByTappingToView(for scrollView: ODScrollView) -> UIView? {
        self.view
    }

    /**
     #Optional

     Resets the scroll view offset - which is adjusted before - to beginning its position after keyboard hid by tapping to the provided UIView via hideKeyboardByTappingToView.

     ## IMPORTANT:
     This feature requires a UIView that is provided by hideKeyboardByTappingToView().
     */
    func isResettingAdjustmentEnabled(for scrollView: ODScrollView) -> Bool {
        true
    }
}
```

**7 -** Optional: You can adjust the ODScrollView when the cursor overlaps with keyboard while typing in multiline UITextInput. trackTextInputCursor(for UITextInput) must be called by UITextInput functions that is fired while typing.

```swift
/**
## IMPORTANT:
This feature is not going to work unless textView is subView of _ODScrollView
*/
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
       _ODScrollView.trackTextInputCursor(for textView)
   return true
}
```