# How to scroll UITableView When Keyboard hides the bottom half section of the screen

Tags: ios, uitableview

This is my custom design

I am trying to implement 2 simple `UITableView`. 1st `UITableView` covers top half of the screen and 2nd `UITableView` covers the bottom half of the screen. Each cell in the `UITableView` has an embedded UITextField. Whenever I select one of the (2nd UITableView) bottom text boxes, The Keyboard slides up, but the `UITableView` does not scroll, and the keyboard hides the input fields and 2nd `UITableView` too.

Suggest me what to do in this scenario. I am only using 2 `UITableView`.

For reference please find below links to the images:

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppUWw.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79MEa.png)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use one `UITableView` and use `TPKeyboardAvoidingTableView` class for your `UITableView` this class automatically manages scrolling of `UITextFields` inside `UITableViewCells`. You will get the sample code search on google for `TPKeyboardAvoidingTableView`.

Comment: This is my custom design see Image 2 and Image 3, UITableView Frame is fixed and will not changed. Any other alternate?

Comment: then you need to manually do all things. Try to change your both tableView's classes to TPKeyboardAvoidingTableView that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

There are answers available on stackoverflow related to your problem. Try this one: [iPhone - Keyboard hides TextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307200/iphone-keyboard-hides-textfield)

Comment: This is my custom design see Image 2 and Image 3, UITableView Frame is fixed and will not changed. Any other alternate?

Answer (score 0):

change the height of the tableview when the keyboard is shown and then when it is dismissed reset the height. Hope this answers you question.

Answer (score 0):

PLease use IQKeyboardManager this will automatically Adjust the Scrolling Enough you have to put this code in your AppDelegate:-

```
 import IQKeyboardManagerSwift
 func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

  IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true

  return true
}
```