# How to scroll view when keyboard is appear in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, ios, keyboard, scroll

I tried this but view is too little to scroll up. How can I scroll more ?

```
// Call this method somewhere in your view controller setup code.
- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

}

// Called when the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification is sent.
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
scroll.contentInset = contentInsets;
scroll.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

// If active text field is hidden by keyboard, scroll it so it's visible
// Your application might not need or want this behavior.
CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;
if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, EPostaText.frame.origin) ) {
    CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, EPostaText.frame.origin.y-(aRect.size.height));
    [scroll setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
}
}

// Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent
- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
scroll.contentInset = contentInsets;
scroll.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
EPostaText = textField;

}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
EPostaText = nil;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307200/iphone-keyboard-hides-textfield/6452886#6452886

Answer (score 2):

The best approach - it is resize the scroll view container to visible area and use this:

```
- (void)scrollRectToVisible:(CGRect)rect animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I found it, I use [TPKeyboardAvoiding](http://icodetricks.wordpress.com/2014/02/12/uitextfields-and-keyboard-issues/)

It is working great, and is very easy to setup:

1. Add a UIScrollView into your view controller's xib
2. Set the scroll view's class to TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView (still
   in the xib, via the identity inspector)
3. Place all your controls within that scrollview

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is my code, hope it will help you. It work ok in case you have many textfield

```
CGPoint contentOffset;
bool isScroll;
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    contentOffset = self.myScroll.contentOffset;
    CGPoint newOffset;
    newOffset.x = contentOffset.x;
    newOffset.y = contentOffset.y;
    //check push return in keyboar
    if(!isScroll){
        //180 is height of keyboar
        newOffset.y += 180;
        isScroll=YES;
    }
   [self.myScroll setContentOffset:newOffset animated:YES];
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    //reset offset of content
    isScroll = NO;
    [self.myScroll setContentOffset:contentOffset animated:YES];
    [textField endEditing:true];
    return  true;
}
```