# Forms in iOS5 (fileds obscured, next/done for numpads)

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard

I am designing a form in iOS 5, where i'm showing the following fields.

1. User Id  - Numpad Keyboard
2. Pin Number - Numpad Keyboard
3. Password - ASCII capable
4. Confirm Password - ASCII capable

I have a number of problems.

1. When the keyboard is on screen, fields which are displayed at the bottom are obscured by the keyboard. How do i show them?
2. There is no next/done button implementation for Numpad Keyboard type. A custom implementation as discussed in SO on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347779/how-to-navigate-through-textfields-next-done-buttons) has the problem, that i have ASCII keyboards too, which display next buttons at the bottom. and while being displayed in the landscape mode, there is no room left for the form.

Comment: Well, there are already lot of questions exists on SO and google. Please try to spend some time with search before asking the question. Here is the [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307200/iphone-keyboard-hides-textfield) for your question

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to navigate through textfields (Next / Done Buttons)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347779/how-to-navigate-through-textfields-next-done-buttons)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two parts to this.

1. Keeping controls in view when the keyboard appears.
2. Having previous/next/done buttons on any keyboard.

For the first part, you want to use a scroll view. See: [Moving Content That Is Located Under the Keyboard](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW7).

For the second part, you want to set a input accessory view. See: [Input Views and Input Accessory Views](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH12-SW2).

Hope that helps.