# Is there a recommended or even automatic way to move a UITextField into view when editing it?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uikit, uitextfield

Having implemented this now in various flavors, I wonder: if editing starts on a `UITextField` and the keyboard appears, is there a recommended or even automated way that would keep the textfield visible by scrolling it up?
I think it would be easiest and best to scroll up the whole root view. Is there something in the API I've been missing so far, that would save me from writing this code myself?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITextField: move view when keyboard appears](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775860/uitextfield-move-view-when-keyboard-appears)

Answer (score 1):

I sit all my UITextFields on a contentView (In my example I have called this view '**movableView**') and then when the user taps one of the text fields

```
//The hardcoded 10's and 20's are the origin of the view before
//the user starts messing with it! 

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    [self scrollViewToTextField:textField];
    //Other stuff I want to do here
    return YES;
}

- (void)scrollViewToTextField:(id)textField
{
    UITextField* tf = (UITextField*)textField;

    CGPoint newOffset = tf.frame.origin;
    newOffset.x = 10;
    newOffset.y = 20 - newOffset.y;

    //This is a category method on UIView which simply adjusts the views
    //frame over a delay.
    [self.movableView moveToX:newOffset.x andY:newOffset.y withDuration:0.3f];
}
```

When the editing is finished you have to move the view back

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    [self resetView];
    // do other stuff here such as grab the text and stick it in ivars etc.

}

-(void)resetView {
    [self.movableView moveToX:10.0f andY:10.0f withDuration:0.3f];
}
```

Just in case - here is the category method for completeness

```
//  UIView+BasicAnimation.h
-(void) moveToX:(CGFloat) x andY:(CGFloat) y withDuration:(NSTimeInterval) duration;


//  UIView+BasicAnimation.m
-(void) moveToX:(CGFloat) x andY:(CGFloat) y withDuration:(NSTimeInterval) duration {
    CGRect newFrame = self.frame;
    newFrame.origin.x = x;
    newFrame.origin.y = y;

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"BasicAnimation" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];

    self.frame = newFrame;

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: I use almost this exact same format, works quite well and once implemented it's very easy to add multiple text views later on.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any such thing exists and it seems like an odd omission.  When you consider the existence of iPad split keyboards, it seems even more like something that should be done correctly once and provided in the API.

For a current project, I'm trying out `TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView`.  (https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding)

Answer (score 0):

It's common to implement this by using an `UIScrollView` and modifying the content offset when a field gains firstResponder status.