# iOS: How to adjust height of area covered by keyboard in iOS

Tags: ios, keyboard

Im curious about a feature in iOS. Please help me out here if you can.

Scenario: I am using a text box where name is entered. Its on lower half of the screen. Just below the text box is a label which displays the number of characters remaining(e.g.like in a twitter feed).

Problem: When i place the text box in upper half of the screen. both the text field and label are visible. But when I place them in lower half, the apple keyboard covers the label part.
Is there a way where I control the area covered in such a way that the label below is also visible?
I hope I have made myself clear enough.
Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present

Comment: http://blog.avabodh.com/2012/03/making-ios-text-fieldview-visible-which.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775860/uitextfield-move-view-when-keyboard-appears?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here i have used delegate method for `UITextView` Same way you can do for `UITextField`

-Here in this code when user starts entering values in `textview` it makes your view's hight lesser then its original with animation

-When user Ends Entering values, it will make your view's size original size.

```
-(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{

    CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
    frame.origin.y = -100;
    [self.view setFrame:frame];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
-(void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    [self.view setFrame:frame];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

 }
```

If you want to know about delegates this [link](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_uitextview_uitextviewdelegate_2/) helps you

Answer (score 2):

Well in that case you have to move the textbox when the keyboard pops up.You can have the notification registered to know when the keyboard pops up and a scrollview to scroll the whole content up the screen can do the job for you

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1126726/1704346),It explains well how to manage something like this

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK You can't control the size of iOS native Keyboard, all you can and should be doing is, making them a subivew of a scroll view and scroll it up.

So the usual practice go something like this.

- Subscribe to the Keyboard notification. `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`
- In the method which the Notification listener will be invoking, set the scrollView's content size accordingly and set the content offset.

  ```
  self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 267);
  self.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, localKeyboardFrame.size.height, 0); 
  [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:<rect of view you want to scroll to> animated:YES];
  ```
- Undo the changes when the keyboard hides, with the help of appropriate notification.`UIKeyboardWillHideNotification`

  ```
  self.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
  ```

And here is [iOS Human Interface Guide's explanation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW7) on it.

Comment: scrolling is not the solution because the label shown should be simultaneously viewed by the user while entering values in text box.

Comment: make the textview and your ui label to be in one view and sub-view it to the scrollView

Comment: changing position of view elements as per the other answer is a solution, but changing your frame position for something like this not optimal neither recommended.

Comment: [regarding positioning view with keyboard](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW7)

Answer (score 1):

Add following to your `viewDidLoad` Method

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(showKeyboard) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(hideKeyboard) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

And after that-- Declare the following 2 methods in your .m file

```
-(void)showKeyboard {
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"slide" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -100);
    [UIView commitAnimations]; }

-(void)hideKeyboard {
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"slide" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.1];
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0);
    [UIView commitAnimations]; }
```