# iOS Keyboard is tiny after rotation to landscape

Tags: ios, keyboard, uitextfield, uitextview

This one has had me stumped all day. On an iPhone 6 running the latest iOS (8.4), the keyboard that appears for a `UITextField` or `UITextView` is appearing as a tiny sliver in the bottom left quadrant of the screen. As long as I keep the phone in the default portrait orientation there is never a problem. As soon as the app switches to landscape is when the keyboard starts appearing as a sliver. If I close the app and reopen, the problem goes away.

**To recap:**

- **Open app in portrait > tap UITextView = keyboard looks normal**
- **Dismiss keyboard > rotate phone to landscape > rotate back to portrait > tap UITextView = keyboard is displayed as a narrow sliver**
- **Dismiss keyboard > close app > open app > tap UITextView = keyboard is normal again**

I've implemented the callbacks for `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` and `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775860/uitextfield-move-view-when-keyboard-appears/12402817#12402817), and the keyboard frame is showing the same for both occasions which is weird. I cannot reproduce this on an iPod 5 running iOS 8.0 or an iPhone 4 running iOS 7.0. Maybe it is useful to add that *the app is not optimized for iPhone 6 screen size* yet.

**Before any rotation:**

[image]

**After rotation to landscape and back:**

[image]

**What could possibly be causing this oddity?**

Answer (score 0):

So I would have never suspected it, but this issue was occurring solely because the app was not optimized for the iPhone 6 screen. Once I added `Launch screen interface file base name` to my `info.plist`, the issue went away. I hope this helps someone down the road.